# R: How to save a comparison.cloud plot into a list

Tags: r, plot, word-cloud

I need a way to save the plot into a list ,apparently it doesn't when i do this

```
   g3 = comparison.cloud(tdm, colors = brewer.pal(nemo, "Dark2"),
               scale = c(3,.5), random.order = FALSE, title.size = 1.5)
```

this is because im trying to save my plots into a list

```
     graph = list(g1,g2,g3)
```

Edited:
Sorry , here are the packages im using

```
   library(twitteR)
   library(sentiment)
   library(plyr)
   library(ggplot2)
   library(wordcloud)
   library(RColorBrewer)
```

Comment: You haven't stated the package you're using.  Also what do you mean by save the plots?  Do you mean save an image of the plot?  `comparison.cloud` doesn't return anything.  The last line is `invisible()` so you are really saving `NULL`

Comment: What i meant is like loading it into a variable , so that i can later just use print(g3) to print out the graphs just like how i save my ggplot2 graphs

Comment: It is base not grid so you can't save them like that.  You could make it into a function though `clouds <- function() {comparison.cloud(tdm, colors = brewer.pal(nemo, "Dark2"),
               scale = c(3,.5), random.order = FALSE, title.size = 1.5); NEXT_CLOUD; LAST_CLOUD}` and then call `clouds()`